# Running Junit in both Eclipse and unix

Tags: java, eclipse

I know this is basic Java Eclipse question.  But, if I create Junit test cases from Eclipse and be able execute them in Eclipse.

Can I also take same test cases in run them in unix/linux envirnment?  Do I need to set different in eclipse in order to run them in unix/linux envirnment?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The Java Virtual Machine (JVM) is fully platform-independent. Any JUnit tests that work on one OS, such as Windows, will work on another, such as Linux.

To run a JUnit test inside UNIX/Linux, you can:

- Install and run it from Eclipse, just like you would on any other OS (Eclipse, being built in Java, is also platform-independent).
- Run `java org.junit.runner.JUnitCore test class` in the terminal, where `test` is the name of the test you want to run, and `class` is the class that that test resides in.